# How to display 2 images as parallelogram next to each other with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert the following image to HTML/CSS.

[image]

There are two images next to each other seperated by a white border.

I tried it with clip-path and `transform: skew()` but nothing really worked.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Share your code so we can help you

Comment: Did my answer below provide what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clip-path`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
#img1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0% 100%, 50% 100%);
}
#img2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -72px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt='view' id="img1" class="images" />
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY=" alt='powder' id="img2" class="images" 
/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS code as a template:

```
.parallelogram {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: www.example.com;
    transform: skew(25deg);
}
```

Let me know if it works!